# In SAS, how to perform a nested test to compare two nested cox regression models?

Tags: sas, cox-regression

In SAS, is there a PROC that can let me perform a nested test to compare two nested cox regression models? If so, how to do it?

I've searched and tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
proc phreg data=mydata;
  model time*event(0) = x1 x2 x3 x4; /* full model */
  model time*event(0) = x1 x2; /* reduced model */
  test x3 x4; /* test the effect of x3 and x4 in the full model */
run;
```

Thank you!

Comment: I bet there is.

Comment: @DirkHorsten very humorous answer. Do you know how? Thanks!

Comment: If we can't help you, try stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DirkHorsten interestingly the question I posted on stats.stackexchange.com was closed because it is a program-related question. Now, this is the only place I could hope to await some help.